# parallel_tests - Ruby multiple browser testing

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, parallel-testing, multiple-browsers

So far I have tried running multiple scenarios using parallel_tests and they are working fine. But the problem with this approach is I need to run multiple times with different browser parameter and I think that this is not a good practice.

Right now I am passing only browser parameters along with cucumber config. I can pass array of browsers like 'chrome', 'firefox' , 'ie' etc. Now question is, is there anyway I can trigger all scenarios against all these browsers? parallel_tests should invoke my scenarios? (Lets say 2 scenarios) 6 times (1 scenario against 3 browsers). Is there anyway I can achieve this task?

Comment: Som why wouldn;t you use Selenium grid for that purposes? You are running selenium grid nodes and running one browser on 1 node. You are defining browser right while running selenium grid node, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685928/selenium-grid-with-cucumber

Comment: Thank you, I totally agree to that point. I know that Grid will take care if we send request with capabilities. But my question is how do i handle within framework to accept multiple browser parameter and trigger all the tests against those browsers? The link that you posted will help me to run multiple tests against single browser( though runs in parallel). But any idea to handle multiple scenarios against multiple browsers ?

Comment: You probably was not carefully reading the answer from the link above. They are doing that in multiply browsers and detecting what browser should be set within the node with envuronment variables.